# Missing Shape Fill Symbol option for point feature class in arcgis pro 3

Tags: arcgis

I am using ArcGIS PRO 3.0.3.  Does anyone know why a point feature layer would have the "Shape Fill Symbol" option not available?

For example this point feature layer has the "Shape Fill Symbol" option:

[image]

However this point feature layer does not have the "Shape Fill Symbol" option:

[image]

I would like to have the "Shape Fill Symbol" in the second layer shown above.  I am sure this is something very simple to fix, just not sure what I am missing.  Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!  I was able to bring back the **shape fill symbol** by doing the following "Reset" routine steps:

1. Click on the "Gallery" tab in the symbology settings:

[image]

2. Select the very first symbol called "Circle 1" as follows:

[image]

3. Click back to the "Properties" tab and the "Shape Fill Symbol" option is now back:

[image]

Make sure you click on the **Apply** button on the bottom once you have finished customizing the colors to save the settings.  Hope this helps someone.